# Maintain multiple instances of the Relam

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, realm

I am developing a SDK , a static library which will be sold to third parties. This static library will be using Relam as the data store.

I am planning for a scenario where my client also has a data store using Relam on his app. I do not want them to change / migrate their data store because they are incorporating my SDK.

Can we have multiple data stores / instances when using Relam ?

Or Is there any other better way to handle this situation ?

Comment: Was going through the Relam documentation , https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#realm-configuration . Will having a separate configuration solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this in two parts:

**Part 1 - Code Architecture**

If you're internally using Realm in a library, and you're worried that your use of Realm might bleed into a user's code if they're also using Realm, there are ways to mitigate this.

You're correct in that using `RLMRealmConfiguration` will let you properly separate the majority of your Realm implementation from theirs. You can use the `fileURL` property to explicitly dictate where your Realm file will be saved, and the `objectClasses` property to explicitly define that only your own `RLMObject` classes will be saved to it.

This may need testing, but the opposite is also true. Realm uses Objective-C reflection to add all `RLMObject` classes by default. As such, unless the user also specifies `objectClasses` in their configuration, the schema for your library's model objects may appear in their Realm files. This would be harmless, but it may look strange to the user.

**Part 2 - Distribution**

It's not great to have 2 copies of the same framework in one static binary. Especially when it's conceivable that the user could start using a newer version of Realm than what's in your library. As such, I'd definitely recommend keeping Realm as a dynamic framework dependency for your library; so both your library and the user's code can target the same codebase.